# What is the most cost effective way for me to sign all my apps?

Tags: digital-certificate

I've developed quite a number of shareware programs over the last number of years and I sell 10 or so online, I've noticed with Windows Vista and Windows 7 and now even my AV scanner warns me my programs aren't signed. So what is the most affordable way for me to sign my many installers? I don't want to pay per program as this would be expensive as I develop a lot and post many as freeware.

Thanks
Jade

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just checked prices of various provides you can buy Code Signing Certificates from (prices represent best value per year converted from local currency to USD):

- **Comodo** $166.55
- **Thwate** $274.50
- **Global Sign** $218.74
- **VeriSign** $431.67
- **GoDaddy** $106.36

I looked into this before for the Open Source software I contribute to, decided I couldn't justify the personal expense.

Answer (score 1):

One [Verisign](http://www.verisign.com/code-signing/content-signing-certificates/microsoft-authenticode/index.html?sl=t41580041570000002)'s code-signing certificate costs $500 per year (a bit less if you buy a multi-year lease) and doesn't limit the number of signatures you perform during that time.  You can surely get cheaper unlimited-use-within-given-time code-signing certificates from other firms, e.g. I see [instantssl](http://www.instantssl.com/code-signing/index.html?ap=GoogleJul10) "Comodo" gives you a 3-years lease for the same $500, while [thawte](https://www.thawte.com/code-signing/index.html?sl=t91530385630000007) is $300 for the first year and a bit less to renew -- however, I have no personal experience with those, and I'm not sure how much those hundred-dollar differences matter to you, so it's hard to give specific advice, beyond the fact that an unlimited-use certificate seems to be the standard approach (indeed I wouldn't even know where to turn for a pay-per-use kind!-)